# pagination not styled in laravel 5.5

Tags: pagination, styling, laravel-5.5

Here is my code where I am showing the paginations of my blog posts !!

```
<div class="clearfix">
    {{ $posts->render() }}
    <a class="btn btn-secondary float-right" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
</div>
```

Here is the controller where the pagination function is called.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = post::where('status',1)->paginate(2);
    return view('user.blog',compact('posts'));
}
```

I have tried lot, but my pagination displayed but not properly styled !!
Why ??

[image: Here I show what is happening above the black line !!]

Answer (score 64, accepted):

To display the pagination links in your blade view:

```
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

Or if you need to specify Bootstrap 4:

```
{{$posts->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
```

Laravel docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?  From the Laravel docs: 'The HTML generated by the paginator is compatible with the Bootstrap CSS framework.'

Comment: I am using laravel 5.5 and boostrap is integrated with it

Comment: How to make it work ? that it shows the proper css ?

Comment: What happens when you specify Bootstrap 4?  {{$posts->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}

Comment: Working for me, Thanks.

Comment: Kerrin solution works perfectly !! Thanks. :) {{$posts->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}

Comment: With `vendor:publish`, artisan command, you can create your own specific pagination template into `view\vendor\pagination`.

Answer (score 16):

For pretty boostrap 4 pagination, simply call this:

```
{{ $results->links( "pagination::bootstrap-4") }}
```

Answer (score 11):

For Laravel 8

Laravel includes pagination views built using Bootstrap CSS. To use these views instead of the default Tailwind views, you may call the paginator's useBootstrap method within the boot method of your App\Providers\AppServiceProvider class:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Comment: worked with me, laravel 8 and bootstrap 5

Answer (score 6):

To add your bootstrap-style to links, you can create your pagination.blade.php that contains something like this

```php
<!-- Previous page symbol "<" Link -->

@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <ul class="pagination">
        {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
            </li>
@else
            <li class="page-item"><a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" class="page-link" rel="prev">&laquo;</a></li>
@endif

{{-- Pagination Elements(represents page number such as 1,2,3) --}}
@foreach ($elements as $element)
{{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
    @if (is_string($element))
            <li class="page-item disabled">{{ $element }}</li>
    @endif

    {{-- Array Of Links --}}
    @if (is_array($element))
        @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                        <li class="page-item active">
                            <a href="#" class="page-link">{{ $page }}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                @else
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a href="{{ $url }}" class="page-link">{{ $page }}</a>
                        </li>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            @endif
        @endforeach

        {{-- Next Page symbol ">" Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li class="page-item"><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" class="page-link" rel="next">&raquo;</a></li>
        @else
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
        @endif
    </ul>
    @endif
```

and than use

```
{{ $results->links('pagination') }}
```